# How to execute command on a Minecraft server

Tags: c++, qt, minecraft

I want to manage a Minecraft server with a Qt Gui. To start the server, I use the system() function to start the server, but to stop it, I have to write the command "stop" on the server console, but I don't know how to do that. Furthermore, I would like to read what is on the console.

Comment: Look at `popen`

Comment: see QProcess...

Comment: QProcess works perfectly, but I cannot connect to the server -_-. When I try, Minecraft says "Connexion refused: no further informations". The problem seems to  come from Qt, as I can connect if I start the server manually. I think QProcess prevent any connection to the server, but I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score -1):

What server host are you using? I tried using https://aternos.org/en/ and that had no issue with it: you might want to try.